# problemas con intercalado de Sting a y b, si es posible asesorar

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, bucle-for, bucles

Detalle de lo solicitado para cada una de las opciones:

**OPCION N° 1** – Combinación de palabras
Construya una función de nombre `combinar( )`, que permita intercalar las letras de dos palabras ingresadas en dos variables y mostrar el resultado por pantalla.
Ejemplo:

```
Cadena1 = “trabajando”
    Cadena2 = “juntos”
```

Debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
Cadena = “tjruanbtaojsando”
```

*Observacines:*

•   La cadena más grande es la que comienza el intercambio; en caso de ser iguales puede comenzar con cualquiera.

•   No se debe permitir cadenas vacías.

```
def intercalar(a, b,):
i = 0
cadena = ""
while(i < len(a)):
    cadena += a[i] + b[i]
    i = i + 1
return cadena
a = input("Ingrese palabara a: ") 
b = input("Ingrese palabara b: ")

print(intercalar(a, b))
```

En si tengo el código, solo que no sirve si el primer ingreso es mas grande que el segundo (en caracteres)

Aquí muestro el error que les comento:

```
Ingrese palabra a: trabajando       
Ingrese palabra b: juntos
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\CarlosIgnacio\Desktop\INACAP\Introduccion a la
> programacion\python\juego de la vida\testfor.py", line 12, in 
> print(intercalar(a, b))   File "c:\Users\CarlosIgnacio\Desktop\INACAP\Introduccion a la
> programacion\python\juego de la vida\testfor.py", line 5, in
> intercalar
> cadena += a[i] + b[i] IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No agregues información en los comentarios, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega la información en la publicación.

Comment: Cuando la cadena b llega a su fin, tu sigues incrementando el valor de `i` e intentas continuar leyendo caracteres que no existen. Tienes que validar que esa cadena llego a su fin y saltear la lectura de la misma permitiendo continuar hasta que termine el `len(a)`

Comment: En resumen, debes obtener el `len(a)` y `len(b)`. Con bloques `IF` te fijas cual inicia primero (tu dices la mas larga) y luego, cuando la mas corta llega a su fin, dejas de leer los caracteres de esa y continúas con la mas larga hasta que termine. No tengo a mano un editor para pasarte el código, pero espero te sirva el comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Una versión mejorada del código sería:

```
def intercalar(a, b):
    #   'a' debe ser mas larga que 'b'.
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a, b = b, a

    cadena = ""
    for i in range(len(b)):
        cadena += a[i] + b[i]
        resto = len(a) - len(b)
        if resto:
            cadena += a[-resto:]
    return cadena
```

Lo primero es asegurarnos de que `a` sea más larga (o igual) que  `b`. Si no es así, intercambiamos los valores:

```
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a, b = b, a
```

Como `a` es más largo que `b`, el intercalado debe ser por el largo de este último, ya que se va a agotar primero:

```
    for i in range(len(b)):
        cadena += a[i] + b[i]
```

Si `a` es más largo, tomamos el resto de `a` usando rebanada de listas:

```
        resto = len(a) - len(b)
        if resto:
            cadena += a[-resto:]
```

Y luego sólo queda retornar el resultado.

Bonus: La función opera correctamente incluso con variables vacías.

#### Demo

```
def intercalar(a, b):
    #   'a' debe ser mas larga que 'b'.
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a, b = b, a

    cadena = ""
    for i in range(len(b)):
        cadena += a[i] + b[i]
    resto = len(a) - len(b)
    if resto:
        cadena += a[-resto:]
    return cadena

tests = [
    ("", ""),
    ("a", ""),
    ("", "1"),
    ("a", "1"),
    ("abcdefg", "123456"),
    ("a", "12345"),
    ("abcdefg", "1")
]

for test in tests:
    print(f"Palabra a: {test[0]}")
    print(f"Palabra b: {test[1]}")
    print(f"Intercala: {intercalar(test[0], test[1])}")
    print()
```

produce:

```
Palabra a: 
Palabra b: 
Intercala: 

Palabra a: a
Palabra b: 
Intercala: a

Palabra a: 
Palabra b: 1
Intercala: 1

Palabra a: a
Palabra b: 1
Intercala: a1

Palabra a: abcdefg
Palabra b: 123456
Intercala: a1b2c3d4e5f6g

Palabra a: a
Palabra b: 12345
Intercala: 1a2345

Palabra a: abcdefg
Palabra b: 1
Intercala: a1bcdefg


Process finished with exit code 0
```